# WordPress, how translate two different menus correctly with Polylang?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I need help with menu translate. I'm created a two different menus for two pages "Landing" and "Blog". And my code worked fine until I started translating with Polylang.

[Look for images](http://3runbrothers.ru/img/images.html)

Here is the menu code:

```
<?php
    if ( is_page( 'landing' ) ) {
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu'        => 'landing',
          'menu_class'  => 'nav navbar-nav darka',
          'container'   => 'false',
        ) );
    } else {
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu'        => 'blog',
          'menu_class'  => 'nav navbar-nav darka',
          'container'   => 'false',
        ) );
    }
  ?>
```

This code created menu, if help:

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );

function register_theme_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'landing-menu'    => __('Landing Menu'),
      'blog-menu'       => __('Blog Menu')
    )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'register_theme_menus');
```

**UPD**:

> I solved this problem!

**functions.php**

```
    <?php
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
// create menu
function register_theme_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'primary' => __('Primary Menu', 'nameyourtheme'),
      'second' => __('Second Menu', 'nameyourtheme')
    )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'register_theme_menus');
?>
```

**header.php**

```
    <?php
if (is_front_page()) {
  wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location'        => 'primary',
      'menu_class'  => 'nav navbar-nav darka',
      'container'   => 'false',
    ) );
}  
else {
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'        => 'second',
    'menu_class'  => 'nav navbar-nav darka',
    'container'   => 'false',
  ) );   
}
?>
```

Comment: I solved this problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with translating more than one menus but my case was a bit different. In my case the two menus were on the homepage located in the header.

**functions.php**

```
'top_menu' => __('Top Menu', 'nameyourtheme')
```

This was my original theme menus. Then I removed the underscore like so:

```
'topmenu' => __('Top Menu', 'nameyourtheme')
```

and it worked. Ofcourse the change in the menu name should be applied in the

**header.php**

```
'theme_location' => 'topmenu',
```

My conclusion is that Polylang recognizes only a single word menu name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help, but rather than registering menus, I usually name my menus like this:

```
Menu fr_CA
Menu en_US
```

Then the website can simply load the right one with a one liner using wordpress get_locale().

```
<? wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Menu '.get_locale())); ?>
```

I find this easier than registering menus.